# How can it be (much) cheaper to build a new house than to buy an existing one?

Tags: old-house, new-home

I'm not sure if this is unique where I live or something, but it seems to me that you can have an entirely brand new house built, where you are the first person to ever move into it, for *way* less money than an existing house costs.

An existing house which has been worn and torn for many decades, probably ready to break at any time, with juicy spiders lurking in the attic and basement. Most likely with aging water pipes, inferior heating system, all kinds of issues inside the walls and the foundation, and so on.

Why would I want to pay a huge premium to get an existing house if I can have a new one built by experts for 1/8th of the price?

Is there something I'm missing? We are not talking about some sort of perfect mint condition mansions where some super famous person lived and which has a huge status. We're talking random lousy houses which may be in good condition, but still are "second hand" at the very best, most likely fifth hand or more.

I feel as if I'm not thinking of something.

Comment: I'm guessing the old houses you are thinking of are in extremely desirable locations, or have features that today's restrictive zoning codes outlaw today.

Comment: The old realtors maxim location, location, location.

Comment: Where are you? Are you claiming you can have a new house built for $100,000 in an area where older houses are going for $800,000? Considering how the cost of building materials has been increasing, I am very doubtful of your claims. Also, why do you think new houses are built by "experts" compared to those who built the older houses? In my area, they are tearing down old houses that might have sold for $500,000 and putting up new houses for asking prices of $900,000 and up. I don't see any new houses being offered at prices anywhere near existing home prices.

Comment: @Barry Prefer not to reveal location, but I was just saying "experts" as opposed to me building it myself. And it's difficult to get "final" prices by house building companies, but yeah, it basically seems like that's the kind of ratio between building new and existing houses here.

Comment: @Barry -- you're mixing land and improvement valuations there.  The OP's question is how a basic tract house can be built for say $100k on a fresh subdivision in the burbs, while old houses in the city might go for several times that, *because* most of the value of the city-house is in the land it sits on

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because cost questions are off topic, and this one mostly involves speculation.

Comment: Also, your example is bonkers. Nowhere can you build a new similar house on a similar lot in a similar location for 12.5% of the price of existing offerings.

Comment: @Barry: cost of building matherials, relative to labor costs, has gone down considerably in the timescales at play here. That's a big part of why buildings in e.g. 1900 were so much more ornate than they are now, because back then having some artisans carve a bunch of stuff all day only increased your price by a little bit. Now it's the reverse, where labor costs are enormous, so buildings are considerably plainer.

Comment: My house was built in 1888 and still works fine. Let's see how all those flat pack houses look in 130 years. Personally, I like living on a brick street lined with real trees, within walking distance to many restaurants, bars, and work. I didn't have to worry about off-gassing materials, crappy windows (quality/placement), paper thin walls, loud 4" PVC, non-gas appliances, low-flow fixtures, or malleable trim work...

Answer (score 5):

### The value of those existing houses is in their *land*, but we've rendered it hard for the market to tap into in a useful way

Where your comparison goes awry is in not quite grasping the fact that the price of a house isn't just about how much it costs to build the house.  It also includes the price of the *land* the house sits on, and this is critical, because urban land is a much more prized commodity than our suburban society leads us to believe.  Running pipes, roads, wires, fire and police service, transit access, and even "softer" services like conveniently located shopping and community space to a piece of land connects it into a greater whole, and thus *increases its inherent value*, no matter if the land is merely a sea of featureless grey, or has a skyscraper planted on it.  Furthermore, the more you surround said piece of land with services and commerce, the more its value rises, granting its owner an *economic rent* (unearned windfall, basically).

Before auto-oriented suburbia took over, land developers fairly instinctively grasped this, and planned their developments to maximize the utilization of land, as measured by taxable value per acre.  Hence, structures were built at a human scale, close enough together that you could get about using your own two feet for many things in life, and groups of these were connected to each other by the transit lines of the day.  This concentration of productivity is what built small-town Main Streets across North America, as well as the immensely productive downtowns of major cities, and the walkable urban fabrics so beloved in Europe and parts of the Northeastern US.

Furthermore, the pendulum has swung back towards demand for a pedestrian-friendly lifestyle from the suburban "drive everywhere" design, and since monocrop Euclidean zoning prohibits us from making *more* urban places in most parts of the country that could otherwise accommodate it, we see soaring prices in these neighborhoods.  (This, sadly, wasn't uniform, as many redlined neighborhoods have similar "bones", but the disinvestment and neglect that redlining consigned them to meant that they weren't, and sometimes still aren't, in a position to ride this wave.)

Furthermore, current zoning also makes it difficult to *intensify* places of that nature in response to their soaring land values.  Normally, a million-dollar house lot would get turned into something *more* valuable, such as a three-flat, garden apartments, or small mixed-use building, thus amortizing the cost of the land across more people.  But, that safety valve got screwed shut by restrictive zoning rules, space-eating parking regulations, and other land use controls that prevent much of this valuable land from being used for anything *but* single-family houses.

So, you wind up with million-dollar burned-out hulks in cities, because that land, while in a productive place, isn't able to be utilized effectively, due to machinations of our own design.

Answer (score 3):

Those second hand houses are where people want to be. Location, location, location.

To build a house, you need to buy land first, usually away from where people want to be, because all that land already has used houses on it.

Small city lot in a big city, with a completely burned out house on it(not cleaned up) went for over a million.

Comment: People are crazy if they want to be near other people... And I don't mean that they have to live extremely remote. Just that it's weird to me that they would *want* to be in the middle of where tons of other people live, and pay a massive premium for it.

Comment: Not crazy, just different objectives in life and a different viewpoint of what quality of life is for their lifestyle.

Comment: @Heggenstaller - because other people is what makes life fun. Other people would think you're crazy for wanting to live somewhere where doing absolutely anything outside your property has a mandatory 20 minute car ride.

Comment: Yeah, we saw bank-owned properties in our neighborhood get bulldozed - the empty land was worth more than the 1950s ranch house, since  the new house to go on that land would be a McMansion.

Answer (score 0):

Housing especially a new home in a tract I know those that will jump in and buy before the landscaping and more homes are built, some minor landscaping added to more homes increases the homes value, I have seen a property appreciate because of the location and minor landscaping where the new houses still being built do not have the value add of landscaping and they may have gotten extras that the contractor threw in to get the properties selling it’s a thing once a area becomes popular people flock there and the home prices go up but the landscaping and location are the big adders where I have seen a 4 year old home sell for more than the last ones at the end of the project.

Comment: Ed, your stream of consciousness needs some punctuation. This one's a bit much even for me. :P